# tkinter listbox select and return values from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am fairly new to Python and tkinter and the part I am struggling with now is getting additional values from a MySQL database once I select a business from a listbox.

The listbox will only list the business names, business id or username but when I select on the business, I have some labels that I need to automatically update from the database which do not appear in the listbox.

The labels that need to be updated are:
First Name
Username
Password

The closest I can get is with the code below which updates the 'Username' label with the business name. I have tried so many ways to try and get the relevant value using indexes but can't get it to work.

```
# Select business from listbox
def select_business(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    #our_businesses.get(ANCHOR)
    index = selection[0]
    print('event:', event)
    print('widget:', event.widget)
    print('(event)  current:', event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()))

    username_display_label.config(text=our_businesses.get(our_businesses.curselection()))
    print('---')

# Search businesses
def search_now():
    selected = drop.get()
    sql = ""
    if selected == "Search by...":
        searched_label.config(text="You forgot to pick an option!")
    if selected == "Business Name":
        sql = """SELECT * FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer_Name like ? ORDER BY Retailer_Name ASC"""
        searched_label.config(text="Businesses found:")
    if selected == "Business ID":
        sql = """SELECT * FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer like ? ORDER BY Retailer_Name ASC"""
        searched_label.config(text="Businesses found:")
    if selected == "Username":
        sql = """SELECT * FROM Retailers WHERE Account_ID like ? ORDER BY Retailer_Name ASC"""
        searched_label.config(text="Businesses found:")

    searched = search_box.get()
    #sql = "SELECT TOP 10 Retailer, Retailer_Name, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer_Name = ?"
    name = (f'%{searched}%', )
    global businesses
    businesses = c.execute(sql, name)
    businesses = c.fetchall()

    #Clear the listbox
    our_businesses.delete(0, END)

    if not businesses:
        searched_label.config(text="Business not found")

    else:
        #global business
        for business in businesses:
            totals = len(businesses)
            #print(totals)
            our_businesses.insert(END, str(business[1]))
            searched_label.config(text="Businesses found: " + str(totals))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: we can't run it - so maybe use `print()` to see which part is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`.

Comment: as for me in `select_business()` you should run SQL code to get data from database - but you don't do this. Or if you have all information in `businesses` then you should get from `businesses` - maybe `businesses[index]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run it so I only guess.

It seems you have all information in global variable `businesses` so you could use it to get row with data

Something like this:

```py
def select_business(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    index = selection[0]

    person = businesses[index]   # row from database

    first_name_display_label.config(text=peron[0])
    username_display_label.config(text=peron[1])
    password_display_label.config(text=peron[2])
```

Comment: thanks for your comments and for the above answer. I have been using 'print' to debug and I think I did it on the global 'business' variable and it just looped and printed: None, None None.... on separate lines. I will have another play around with this global variable and come back to you!

Comment: maybe you could create minimal working code (with some data) so we people could copy and run it to search problem.

Comment: after your comments and fixing the way I was using the indexes, it is now working as it should. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: if you want you may describe your fixes as answer and you may mark your answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote your answer.

Comment: added the fixes as a comment and accepted it as the answer. Unfortunately I am unable to upvote your answer or mine as I haven't got enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within the 'select business' function. As I had the 'businesses' as a global variable, I could just get the row I needed with indexing.

However, you need to make sure your indexing is correct as I found that I was mis-counting and the selected indexes I used were blank in the database!

Here is the correct function:

```
def select_business(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    index = selection[0]
    retailer = businesses[index]
    businessname_display_label.config(text=retailer[1])
    firstname_display_label.config(text=retailer[3])
    username_display_label.config(text=retailer[33])
    password_display_label.config(text=retailer[34])
    email_display_label.config(text=retailer[13])
```

Comment: Actually the logic is the same as the answer from @furas, why don't you accept his answer instead of posting duplicate answer?